# Solving differential equations given a companion matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, companion-matrices

So i'm given a differential equation

$$f'''(t)-2f''(t)-f'(t)+2f(t)=0$$ where $$t\in \mathbb{R}$$

and

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
-2 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

the polynomial assosiated with $C$, $p(t)=t^3-2t^2-t+2$

Now assume that $f(t)$ is a solution of the differential equation and set that $\vec{x}(t)=(f(t),f'(t),f''(t))$

Question: How do I check that $\vec{x}(t)$ is a solution of the first order of systems?

Attempt:

Since this is disconnected we can solve it this way:

First we find the diag of $C$

which in this case is $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{4}& 1\\ 1 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},D=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0& 0 \\0&2&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then proceeed to solve the disconnected system $$\vec{y}'=D\vec{y}$$

$$\vec{y}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}C_1e^{t}\\C_2e^{2t}\\C_3e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $$C_1,C_2,C_3\in \mathbb{R}$$

Which will  help us solve $\vec{x}(t)=P\vec{y}(t)$

$$\vec{x}(t)=P\vec{y}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{4}+C_3e^{-t}\\ C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{2}-C_3e^{-t}\\C_1e^t+C_2e^{2t}+C_3e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

This is where i'm pretty much stuck... What am I supposed to do now? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: First you find $e^{Ct}.$ If you have $C = Q^{-1}D Q$ for diagonal $D,$ then $e^{Dt}$ is also diagonal with those exponential terms, after which $e^{Ct} = Q^{-1}e^{Dt} Q.$  At the very, very end, given an $x(0) = x_0,$ you get $x = e^{Ct} x_0$

Comment: I guess I can tell what you mean by disconnected. You need to figure out both my matrices $Q$ and $Q^{-1}.$ I suppose your $P$ is one of them, not sure which.

Comment: $P$ is your $Q$ I guess. I think I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good.

Now you  have to show that $$x'=Cx$$

That is you have to take derivative of $$ \begin{pmatrix}C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{4}+C_3e^{-t}\\ C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{2}-C_3e^{-t}\\C_1e^t+C_2e^{2t}+C_3e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

and show that it is the same as

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
-2 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}      \begin{pmatrix}C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{4}+C_3e^{-t}\\ C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{2}-C_3e^{-t}\\C_1e^t+C_2e^{2t}+C_3e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: They don't seem pretty identical

Comment: for $x'=$$\begin{pmatrix}C_1e^t& C_2e^{2t}/2 & -C_3e^{-t}\\
C_1e^t & C_2e^{2t} & C_3e^{-t}\\
C_1e^t& 2C_2e^{2t} & -C_3e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$ Which is not the same as $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
-2 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}      \begin{pmatrix}C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{4}+C_3e^{-t}\\ C_1e^t+\frac{C_2e^{2t}}{2}-C_3e^{-t}\\C_1e^t+C_2e^{2t}+C_3e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Check your $ x'$ again, it has to be a vector not a matrix.

Comment: Ah, i got it now. Just an arithmetic error. Thanks!

Comment: Good, thanks for your attention .

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: Yes, of course, what is the question?

Comment: How can I find all real solutions for the system $x'=Cx$ can I for example set the different variables $C_1=1, C_2=2,C_3=-1$?

Comment: Yes, you have the general solution when you keep your parameters $ C_1,C_2,...$ free. For a specific initial value you find specific parameters by plugging in your initial values.

Comment: What if I'm not given any initial value?

Comment: I understand that if i'm given initial conditions ex: x(0) =(-1,2,2) I can use Laplace transform to solve it

Comment: Then you just keep your $C_1,C_2,...$

Comment: It's not supposed to be in matrix form right?

Comment: It could be in matrix form as well.